# How can I pass the output of an http call as input to another http call in Rx JS?

Tags: rxjs, angular5, rxjs5, rxjs-pipeable-operators

Hi I am getting an error when i tries to do the following operation

```
export class FlightFormTemplatesStepComponent
{

 tagonMessagePrefix: TagOnMessagePrefix;


  ngOnInit() {
     this.flightService.get(this.flightId).pipe(
         tap (flight => {this.flight = flight}),
         mergeMap( (flight) => {
           return this.flightService.getTagonMessagePrefix(flight);
         })
        ).subscribe(
          (tagonMessagePrefix) => { this.tagonMessagePrefix = tagonMessagePrefix}

        );
   }
}
```

this is the error I am recieving.

```
property) FlightFormTemplatesStepComponent.tagonMessagePrefix: TagOnMessagePrefix
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'TagOnMessagePrefix': id, flightName, flightTagonTypes, configuredGlobalTagonSettings, tagonTextts(2739)
```

Any idea how can i fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed to map operation and it works

```
this.flightService.get(this.flightId).pipe(
 tap (flight => {this.flight = flight}),
 switchMap( (flight) => {
   return this.flightService.getTagonMessagePrefix(flight);
 })
).subscribe(
  (tagonMessagePrefix:TagonMessagePrefix) => { this.tagonMessagePrefix = tagonMessagePrefix}

);
```